# React js adding product detail page error: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `to` supplied to `Link`, expected one of type [string, object, function]

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build product detail page for my first ecommerce website, and run into this problem when I want to click one of the product at the home page and direct to the product detail page:

It supposes to show the product detail page "DetailProductPage" when I click one of the product title,the browser still shows the path :local3000/product/{productid},but fail to show the detailproductpage and I got an error in console: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `to` supplied to `Link`, expected one of type [string, object, function]

Below is the code, and the current website is weiwhite.com

`In App.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {auth} from './firebase';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import Footer from './Footer';
import DetailProductPage from './DetailProductPage';


function App() {
  

  return (
    <Router>
    <div className='App'>
      <Switch>
        ...
        <Route path='/'> 
          <Header />
          <Home />
          <Footer />
        </Route>
        
        <Route path='/product/:productId'> 
          <DetailProductPage />
        </Route>

        </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`In Product.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Product.css";
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {Card} from 'antd';
import DetailProductPage from './DetailProductPage';


function Product({item}) {

   const [{basket},dispatch]=useStateValue();

   const addToBasket=() =>{
     //dispatch the item into the data layer
      dispatch ({
        type:'ADD_TO_BASKET',
        item: {
          id: item.id, 
          title: item.title,
          image: item.image,
          price: item.price,
        },
      });
   };

  return (
  <div className='product'>
    <a href="https://www.etsy.com/shop/weiwhiteart">
    {/* <a href={`/product/${item.id}`}> */}
    <img src={item.image} alt="" />
    </a>
    
     <div className='product_info'>
    <a href={`/product/${item.id}`}>
     <p className='product_title'>{item.title}</p>
     </a>
    
      <p className='product_price'>
            <small>$</small>
            <strong>{item.price}</strong>
      </p>
        {/* <div className='product_rating'>
            {Array(rating).fill().map((_, i) =>(<p></p>))} 
        </div> */}
      <button onClick={addToBasket}> Add to Basket</button>
     </div>
    {/* </Link> */}
      

  </div>
  );

}

export default Product;
```

`In Products.js`

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Product from "./Product";
import { productItems } from "./Data";


const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
`;

const Products = () => {
  return (
      <Container>
          {productItems.map(item =>(
              <Product item={item} key={item.id}/>
          ))}
      </Container>
  );
};

export default Products;

in Datas.js


export const productItems = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: "../Swiming_fish_W.png",
        title: "Swim Fish",
        price:49.99,
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        image: "../Duckling_W.png",
        title: "Bath Duckling",
        price:49.99,
    },
...
```

`in DetailProductpage.js`

```
import React from 'react'

function DetailProductPage() {
  return (
    <div>DetailProductPage</div>
  )
}

export default DetailProductPage
```

Comment: I'm guessing you used `Link` without giving it a `to` prop?

Comment: I did "<Link to={`/product/${item.id}`}>" or  <a href={`/product/${item.id}`}>. both of them can not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found that in App.js, the route to './product/:id' have to be placed above the home page '/'. after this change, everything works well.